# Could moderators have some long-term activity data between "quarter" and "all time"?

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

The moderator dashboard includes useful tallies of things like flags handled, comments deleted, questions mod-closed, and so on.  We can view this information for the current day, week, month, quarter... or all time.  Missing from this list is year.

Several times now I have found myself wanting to answer questions like "are we getting more flags than we used to or does it just feel that way?".  We can *sort of* assess this for the recent past by comparing month to quarter, but fluctuations like holidays or current events can throw that off.  On the other hand, "all time" doesn't provide the right perspective on sites that are several years old.  Being able to see trends over six months or a year would be more helpful.

Why do I want to answer questions like these?  Because sometimes it feels like the mod team is doing more work, but maybe the *work* hasn't changed but *we're* doing something wrong or need a vacation or something.  When perceptions of increased workload lead to the beginnings of conversations about whether we should ask SE for another moderator, I'd like to be able to sanity-check perceptions against data.  If our perceptions are off, that's a different problem that we might need to attack in a different way.

Adding a "year" tab to the existing dashboard is one approach.  (That *seems* not too hard.)  Adding moderation stats to the mod analytics, so we could see (aggregate, not per-mod) graphs of these events over time like we can for posts, visits, votes, etc, would let us see trends over time including cyclical changes, but might be more work.  Maybe there are other ways to share the information with mods too; I'm requesting functionality, not a specific interface.  It's just that "ping Shog in TL and ask" doesn't scale.

Comment: *It's just that "ping Shog in TL and ask" doesn't scale*, this must be verified. Brb, creating a "we all ping shog" at 11UTC event.

Comment: @BhargavRao ping-storms are easy; he can handle (or dismiss) them all at once. What really doesn't scale is the Chinese-water-torture pings -- one or two an hour, every hour, nonstop, enough to drive even the toughest of Shogs mad.  Do *you* want to take your chances on that?

Answer (score 13):

The route to get the detailed admin dashboard for an year *exists*, but the UI does not display it. You can get the yearly stats by navigating to the page manually.

What you can do is, to click on one of tabs, month, day, etc, and change the `filter` query parameter to `year`. `https://{sitename}/admin?filter=year` would be the route which you will need to check.

That said, an UI to directly do this would be great, or a userscript, atleast.

Comment: Thanks for that - had never realised we could do that.

Comment: Wow, did not realize that!  If adding another option creates a UI problem (I can see how it might get cramped), I'd much rather see "year" baked in and "day" the thing you need to modify the URL for.  I've never seen the day view used for anything other than informal competitions in TL ("ha, *I've* handled *this many* flags today!").

Comment: Wow, that's amazing. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Anyone know if this is rolling? (i.e. 1  year is the past 365 days) or calendar (e.g. 1 year is since Jan 1, 2018)?

Comment: @ɥʇǝS looks like rolling, else year and quarter right now would be the same.  (They're nowhere near each other on the site I just checked.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio: Doing the yearly report is pretty hard on the servers.  I've had it time out on me several times.  Even the monthly is still pretty slow returning data.

Comment: @RobertHarvey presumably the "all" tab is a complete non-starter for you, then.  #SOModProblems :-)